# How to create Screen sizes of Live Code application compatible to Iphone,Android All Screens

Tags: livecode

I have developed an app which i want to run on every platform that LiveCode supports.I have Created app for 480x800 size.Now when i test it in Iphone and android.App is taking a static size.so it looks odd when testing under various sizes.how can i make it compatible for all sizes.that something should be there which can automatically resize the app with screen size.

Comment: Is there no one who can answer this?

Answer (score 2):

We are currently implementing resolution independence into LiveCode and this will bring automatic scaling to your applications.

In the mean time, you will have to use one of the following options-

1) Programmatically resize your stack-

http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=14859

2) Use one of the following 3rd party plugins-

http://buchwald.ca/developer-tools/

http://mobgui.com/morph.php

http://www.gadgetplugins.com/altplugins/altMobileResizer.rev

Comment: Is it mean i need to programatically set the size for every screen, and also locations and size of every controls in particular screen with respect to device sizes?

Comment: altMobileResizer seems like to be great thing.But can you help me to install it with my livecode?

Comment: By implementing the method similar to the example in the first link above, you application should automatically scale to any device resolution. This should also include controls

Comment: this lesson will explain the steps needed to install a 3rd party plugin- http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/21341-how-to-install-custom-user-plugins

Comment: I have installed a AltMobileResizer.But i am little worried about images,with resizing the images blurred.It looses its actual grace.How can i get rid of this problem?

Comment: you will need to Import your graphics including button icons at the largest size for your app (possibly iPad retina) and set their quality to "good", manually resize them so they look good on your smallest stack size. This is taken from here- http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=14859

Answer (score 1):

LiveCode 6.5 included a fullscreenMode property. This will scale an app to fit any screen size. You simply create your app at whatever size suits you as a developer and then add the following to your preOpenStack handler:

```
on preOpenStack
   set the fullscreenMode to "exactFit"
end preOpenStack
```